# What does port 127.0.1.1: +23838 do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, kubuntu

When I did a search in my Kubuntu to find out which among files have a 777 permission (I'm new to Linux, I did it while learning about Linux) using the following command:

```
find /home -perm -777 -ls
```

I got these results:

```
1. lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/.kde/cache-kk -/var/tmp/kdecache-usrV
2. lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/.kde/tmp-kk -/tmp/kde-usrVlUogEz
3. lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/.kde/socket-kk -/run/user/1000/ksocket-usrV
4. lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root   /home/usrV/.kde/Autostart/dropboxd/dropboxd -/home/usrV/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
5. lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/.mozilla/firefox/c0vuiyiz.default/lock -127.0.1.1:+23838
6. lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/.local/share/akonadi/socket-kk -/tmp/akonadi-usrV.lw2fVL
7. lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/Documents/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/.config/ibus/bus -/home/usrV/.config/ibus/bus
8. lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root   /home/.directory -/etc/kubuntu-default-settings/directory-home
```

The fifth file is `lrwxrwxrwx   1 usrV    usrV   /home/usrV/.mozilla/firefox/c0vuiyiz.default/lock -> 127.0.1.1:+23838`.

What does the address `127.0.1.1:+23838` do? I am worried that whether it is a security risk to have 777 permission to all these files.

Comment: it looks like firefox is locking a resource and advertising that to other processes using a network port. this is a pretty common practice though I've never seen it in `ls` output. Basically, processes can't talk to each other directly so they use intermediaries like network connections, files, etc. this is called Interprocess communication or IPC. just about any port you have open on the loopback adapter (127.x.y.z) is for IPC. Locks are necessary because shared resources can only be written to by one thread at a time or they may corrupt each other, so its a Flag for other threads to see.

Comment: Note that 23838 was likely arbitrarilly chosen, because it is the lowest open port in the requested range, but who knows. it isn't a reserved port for any standard protocol per IANA.

Comment: @Frank Thomas and dsstorefile1 thanks for your reply. Very informative.